# Getting rid of multiple tagged places / locations in R or QGIS

Tags: r, gis, spatial, qgis

I have a lot of data in a table (Place name Gazetteer) and a lot of places occur multiple of times. But these places which occur multiple of times are either the same location (tagged / saved more than one time) with slightly different long/lat's or the placename is ambiguous so there is another place far away with the same name.

I want to retrieve only the ambiguous placenames (Which is my research about)! I used the duplicated() function to get the duplicated place names. But now I want to merge the duplicates with nearly the same locations. So these placenames must have nearly the same location aswell as the same name.

F.e. here is the data.frame of duplicates with all of them (ambiguous ones aswell as multiply tagged ones)

```
        Names               lat             long            region
58107   Zwüschebäch         46.56039    7.60316     Europe/Zurich
58392   Zwüschebäch         45.00231    7.30079     Europe/Zurich
58392   Zurich Airport      47.45042    8.56242    Europe/Zurich
58392   Zurich Airport      47.450994   8.559343   Europe/Zurich
```

So `Zurich Airport` is the same location but `Zwüschebäch` is ambiguous there are two places which are named the same. So how can I merge `Zurich Airport` based on the same Value (in the column "Name") and the similarity/buffer of the coordinate?

Comment: I would try to use a distance function from the `rgeos` package such as `gDistance(..., byid = TRUE)` or `gWithinDistance(..., byid = TRUE)` for the duplicates identified by name. However, how do you determine the "correct" coordinates of the duplicates?

Comment: additionally, it would be useful if you could share the subset of these four points as a shapefile or so.

Comment: Yes I thought about that aswell, and exactly a problemis also to determine if its "correct" because probably the multiple tagged placenames are probably nearer in a village/small town than in a huge city. I created this example its not from the dataset. I could have a look if I can upload the whole data.frame as csv.

Comment: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/6ab341943453ead59e8045fb65710e7a/example_switzerland.csv example for switzerland of duplicates but instead of names use asciinames because somehow it encoded it wrongly (although UTF-8 was default)

Answer (score -1):

if your entries are sp points, then you can calculate their distances with spdep::dnearneigh 
with the distances established, you can then filter by distance in kilometers and eliminate groups of more than 1 element